# Question from 14.6 "Galois Groups of Polynomials" from Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am confused in the proof of proposition 30 in Dummit and Foote on page 608. Near the end of this "proof" he goes on to say,

> By the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, the fixed field of $S_{n}$ has index precisely $n!$ in $F(x_{1},...,x_{n})$.

I am very confused about how he gets this or even how the Fundamental Theorem applies. By index does he mean the group index? I really don't know what he's talking about...

Explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While you're free to wait for an answerer who happens to have a copy of your text on hand, it would help if you could at least state the proposition.

Comment: He means that the field degree of the big field over the little field is $n!$. Since this number is the cardinality of your group, which is acting as a Galois group of the big over the little, it’s a direct application of FTGT.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it's a popular enough text that it's not unlikely that someone has it on hand

Comment: @Lubin that's kind of what I was thinking.

Comment: @Lubin

Okay thanks, I get it now. The proof is poorly written in my opinion but I see what he's saying now. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: BTW, as far as I can tell, there is a gap in Dummit&Foote's proof.  At least, they have not justified the conclusion that the fixed field "is the field of rational functions in the elementary symmetric functions".  They only show that the fixed field is generated by the $s_k$ over $F$.  You need transcendence degree theory (from section 14.9) to justify this.

Comment: And honestly, they really only gesture at the proof of the existence of transcendence degree in 14.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Proposition is the following.  Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be indeterminates over a field $F$, and let $s_i$ be the $i^\text{th}$ elementary symmetric function in $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

**Proposition 30**: The fixed field of the symmetric group $S_n$ acting on the field of rational functions in $n$ variables $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is the field of rational functions in the elementary symmetric functions $F(s_1, \ldots, s_n)$.

$S_n$ acts on $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ by permuting the subscripts of the $x_i$, so the elements of $S_n$ can be considered as field automorphisms of $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.  Let $K$ be the fixed field of $S_n$. As Lubin points out, then $[F(x_1, \ldots, x_n): K] = |S_n| = n!$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory.